# Does a neuron always holds a scalar value

Tags: neural-network

Does a neuron in a neural network holds only a scalar value as in MLP(Multi layer perceptron). Or does it holds a matrix? I am learning CNN and I am bit confused about how back propagation works if the neuron holds a matrix(Not sure- I think it holds a matrix in convolutional layer)?

Comment: You are also bit confused about StackExchange. Please visit [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What would the matrix contain? Actually, a neuron doesn't contain a scalar, but a function calculating the scalar from a vector obtained by vector multiplication (inputs times weights)

Comment: @YassinHajaj, Yeah that is true about a neuron. But in the convolution layer, say your input is 28x28 image with a filter of 4x4(assuming the stride is [1,1]), the output you will get is 25x25, and this represents the output of the neuron with weights corresponding to the kernel of the filter. So here the neuron holds the output 25x25 right?